# What are "crawling artifacts" in computer graphics?

Tags: graphics, artifacts

I am reading a paper where it says something about that. Googling didn't help that much.

The full sentence is in the section 3.1 of this paper:

http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/pubs/Cole_2010_TFM/cole_tfm_preprint.pdf

Thanks a lot!

C4sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it means temporal aliasing artifacts when rendering lines in animations. They show up as brighter pixels crawling along the line.

Once you know about those, your enjoyment of computer animated movies will decrease significantly. Sorry about. It cannot be undone. :-)